# 'Unlikely associated' or 'unlikely to be associated'

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct and why? Can both be used in some cases?

"A is unlikely associated with B"
"A is unlikely to be associated with B"

"A is unlikely related to B"
"A is unlikely to be related to B"

EDIT: context is academic medical article

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage Stack Exchange! We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: _Unlikely_ requires an infinitive complement with the complementizer _to_. I.e, *_unlikely associated with/related to_ is not grammatical; you need _to be_.

Comment: 'Unlikely associated' will always be wrong. ‘Unlikely to be associated' might be acceptable, depending on the circumstances. Does the difference make sense to you, please?
If you’re suggesting a difference between “Unlikely associated" and "unlikely to be associated" could you explain that difference, please?

Comment: "A is unlikely associated with B" ... I would probably take this to mean: A is associated with B, as unlikely as it may seem.

Comment: @JohnLawler Does that also apply to 'likely' in your opinion? "He's likely working today" isn't something most British people would say but it seems to be increasingly common in US English.

Comment: @BoldBen: No, _likely_, but not _unlikely_, can be used in that construction. Roots grown into different stems often have different affordances.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that I've seen and heard "likely" used to qualify an adjective or participle, as in "He's been working hard all week; he's likely exhausted". This would support a response of "both can be used" to your question. But I'm looking at this [Cambridge Dictionary article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/common-adverbs/likely-and-unlikely), the [Merriam Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likely), and the OED definition, and not finding any examples of it. One of the Merriam Webster glosses, "without great doubt", is consistent with your examples that omit "to be".

So I would say it's *used* but I'm not immediately finding documentation to support its use in elevated writing. However, absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence.

Comment: The CED comment 'In American English, and more and more in British English, _likely, is used as a mid-position adverb (like probably in British English), most commonly between will and a main verb:

The new regulations will likely result in many people losing their jobs.' is critical here, as is the fact that a similar usage of 'unlikely' is not sanctioned. However, [RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unlikely)  does_ sanction an adverbial usage. But ...

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+likely+going+to%2Cis+unlikely+going+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20likely%20going%20to%3B%2Cc0) show that this usage (here, 'is unlikely going to') is far less common. [Ditto](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+likely+associated+with%2Cis+unlikely+associated+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20likely%20associated%20with%3B%2Cc0) for 'is unlikely associated with' compared with 'is likely associated with'.

Comment: Consider "It is unlikely that A is associated with B".  Of the four alternatives listed in the original question above, the last one, "A is unlikely to be related to B", is clearest.